# using md-cards in a md-grid-list in Angular 2 material

Tags: angular, css, angular-material

I am new to angular 2 material design. What I am trying to achieve is to create a grid list using angular2 material and place md-cards inside md-grid-tile. Though the md-card have position:relative, they are overflowing the md-grid-tile. 
[click this link, the cards are overlapping and they are overflowing the md-grid-tile in a md-grid-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8SG5.jpg)

Following is the code that I have used:

```
<body>
    <md-toolbar layout="row"> <md-button class="menu">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon> </md-button>
    <h3>Pipeline UI</h3>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1" gutterSize="15px">
        <md-grid-tile layout-wrap *ngFor="let item of releaseType">
            <md-card flex layout-fill>
                <md-card-header>test1</md-card-header>
                <md-card-content>
            <stage [init]="item.submissions"></stage></md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
</body>
```

Any help to solve this is extremely appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I figured out,`md-grid-tile` creates inside another dom element called `figure` and one of its css rules is `align-items: center;`. I used:

```
md-grid-tile figure {
    align-items: flex-start!important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding this css snipet to the app.component.css (using app.component to display my grid ATM). And it unfortunately doesn't work. Where do you have the style defined? BTW - This fix works when applied directly in chrome debugger.

Comment: The css rule is in another custom css file. The custom rule/file has to be loaded after the default angular material styles because when multiple rules of the same "specificity level" exist, the one that appears last wins.