# Angular Material: making a mat-card fill an entire mat-grid-tile

Tags: angular, layout, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to use `mat-grid-list` to create a grid list layout in which each `mat-grid-tile` contains a `mat-card` that fills the entire tile regardless of the card's content. Most of the cards need to occupy multiple rows and/or columns. So far I haven't been able to get it working.

Things I have tried:

- Setting each card's CSS `width` and `height` to 100% using the selector `mat-card`. This causes each card to fill the entire screen rather than just the `mat-grid-tile` that contains the card.
- Setting each card's CSS `width` and `height` to 100% using the selector `mat-grid-tile > mat-card`. This has the same effect as not having a selector at all, as the cards just remain centered within their grid tiles wrapped to the sizes of the their respective contents.
- Following the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922547/using-md-cards-in-a-md-grid-list-in-angular-2-material). The problem is that the properties `flex`, `layout-wrap`, and `layout-fill` are not available to me, probably  because the sample code is using Angular 2 rather than 4.

Edit: It looks like I misunderstood the results of the first attempt listed above. The cards actually fill just the `mat-grid-tile`s but their surrounding shadows get cut off by the tiles' boundaries.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly is not working for you, but I have just recreated your scenario in stackblitz, and used the following style for `mat-card`:

```css
mat-card {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

Here's the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqs6cp?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

And just in case you are worried (as I was) about the support for css `calc()` here's the supported browsers and versions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

*(answer was updated based on first comment)*

Comment: Thanks. This works well when no tile occupies more than 1 row or column. However, when the tiles occupy varying numbers of rows and/or columns they tend not to align with one another when all of them have the same percent width and height. I realize that one could calculate a specific percent width/height for each card in order to line them up, but that would be a long and inconvenient process. I have updated my question to specify the need for multi-column/row cards.

Comment: Try now, the stackblitz is updated, and they align nicely.

Answer (score 4):

#### The solution without **`calc`**:

You have to make use of `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
parent {
  width: 100%;  /* OR like 95% to make shadows visible */
  height: 100%; /* OR like 95% to make shadows visible */
}

mat-card {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796258/3370568

OR even better:

```css
parent {
  width: stretch;
  height: stretch;
  margin: 5px;
}

mat-card {
  height: stretch;
  width: stretch;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Oops, another solution! You may not even need that `mat-card`.

```html
<mat-grid-tile class="mat-elevation-z4" style="border-radius: 4px;">

</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: I think using the class and the style directly is more straightforward and there's no need to manage `mat-card`. Thanks for sharing.