# Angular 4 - how to make a mat-card fill entire parent component area

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

I have a `mat-grid-tile` (parent) which contains a component `app-window` (child), which contains a `mat-card` at its root.

The `app-window` fills the `mat-grid-tile` as desired and is center-aligned both vertically and horizontally. Now I want the `app-window`'s `mat-card` to do the same so that I can have a grid of equally spaced `mat-card`s.

How can I get the `mat-card` contained within `app-window` to fill the entire `app-window`? I have tried some ideas but none were successful; more details below.

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zvypv)

Component HTML:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="4:3">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <app-window></app-window>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Component CSS:

```
app-window {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

Attempted solutions and their results:

- Setting the `app-window`'s `mat-card`'s width to a `width` and `height` of 100%. This makes the `mat-card` slightly larger than the `mat-grid-tile` that contains it. The desired behaviour would have been to match the size of the `app-window`.
- Not assigning any extra CSS properties to the `mat-card`. As a result, the `mat-card` occupies the `app-window`'s entire width but is only as tall as its content. I want it to always be the same height as the `app-window`.
- Assigning the property `flex-grow: 1;` to the `mat-card`. Based on my understanding, this should make the `mat-card` fill the entire space of the `app-window`, i.e. its parent container. However, there is no effect and the result is the same as the second solution's.

Comment: You seem to need CSS help. CSS doesn't care much what you use to generate the final markup. Right now you require someone who knows well both Angular 4 and CSS to answer your question. Also, they will need to test it by creating a [mcve]. If you create it yourself, linking required resources to reproduce the issue, anyone with sufficient CSS knowledge could help by inspecting the result featured in the snippet, even if they didn't know a thing about Angular 4 and how it builds up that markup.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu question has been updated with a StackBlitz example of my issue.

Answer (score 25):

Hope you have figured this out by now but I'll provide this solution to others who might be seeing similar issues.

The reason `height:100%;` extends past the parent container is the `mat-card` `box-sizing` property is `content-box` by default. If you set it to `border-box` it will subtract the padding while determining the size to fill the parent.

The following should work for you:

```
app-window mat-card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```